# Pet insurance on death of owner

Tags: adoption, insurance

My uncle passed away a couple of days ago and I have been asked to adopt his beagle. The dog has likely a couple of health conditions due to neglect, my uncle was a depressed man for a lot of his life and the dog has been over fed, under excercised and as such, I am concerned that we would be taking on more than what we are being asked to do.

I understand that my uncle had pet insurance for the dog, although nobody at this point can give me specific details.

**The Question**

In the UK, does pet insurance transfer between owners in the event of the original owners' death?

I have read through a handful of policy terms and conditions and cannot seem to see anything relevant whatsoever.

Comment: Most pet insurance I have seen is term insurance, so while it could probably be transferred to the dog's new owner that's likely to be a year of coverage at most, half a year on average. Nice to have but not likely to be a deciding factor in bless you expect the dog to have serious health problems immediately... The vet probably has details of the policy?

Comment: @keshlam - Thanks. It's not a deciding factor on adopting the dog in any way, and I don't see anything immediately obvious that is wrong with him. Along with insurance, no one seems to know which vet saw the dog either so I think it would be prudent to have my local vet look over him, and along that line have an idea of what we can expect as a commitment financially once my cousin has had a chance to go through my uncle's paperwork.

Comment: When you are at your vet, have them check for a micro chip.  If the dog has one, it should point to the vet that placed it, who is probably the dogs vet. You might also call vets around your uncles home to see if they have a record of him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have something that looks lie it's the policy document, then you (or whoever has probate) should really call the insurance company and transfer the policy holders details (just the same as for utility bills and other policies).

At this point, you can confirm the terms of the policy as it applies to the dog and whether a change in ownership (of the dog and policy) affects the policy in any way.

Sorry to hear of your loss, and wish you every success with the beagle.